# Reload index html on route change - angular 15

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this unique requirement where we host a multi tenant application using angular 15.

By default, when a user types http://localhost:4200, we change APP_BASE_HREF to /my so that the URL becomes http://localhost:4200/#/my (we are using hash strategy). 'my' is the default tenant.

User can also directly type http://localhost:4200/#/my which has the same effect as above.

User can also type a different tenant, for e.g. http://localhost:4200/#/th to load a different tenant.

### Problem:

After http://localhost:4200/#/my is loaded (index file and app componentloaded) if the user tries to change the tenant in the same page, for e.g. http://localhost:4200/#/th the index page will not reload and angular router kicks in and there is no route defined for /#/th. Therefore it goes to error page (404).

### Requirement:

I would like to do window.location.reload() if the user changes tenant (index html loads different js files for different tenant). What is the right router event to implement this? or the right approach (javascript vs angular). Any quick solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not something the router would do, you'll have the call the native APIs !

Comment: Written a hashchange listener and reloaded the application on tenant change. However there is a slight glitch, angular first gets to 404 and after that the new URL is loaded.